# How to generate JAR with dependent libs?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

Using Maven, how to generate JAR with dependent libs? I am using mvn package, it does not include dependent libs.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) and configure it to `jar-with-depdencies`.

From the doc:

> For example, imagine that our project produces a JAR. If we want to
>   create an assembly binary that includes our project's dependencies, we
>   can take advantage of one of the Assembly Plugin's prefabricated
>   descriptors, as follows:
>
> ```
> <project>
>  [...]
>   <build>
>     [...]
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
>              org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
>          -->
>         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.3</version>
>         <configuration>
>           <descriptorRefs>
>             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>           </descriptorRefs>
>         </configuration>
>         [...]
> </project>
> ```